# Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, pdo

Im having an error with select statment using pdo, and Im not understanding the reason why this is happening.

Do you see something wrong here?

**I'm having this error:**

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in    $readGallery->execute();

```
$delId = $_GET['delid'];
$thumb = $_GET['thumb'];
$folder = '../uploads/';
$readGallery = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE news_id = ?");
$readGallery->bindParam(':news_id', $delId);
$readGallery->execute();
$numGallery =   $readGallery->rowCount();
```

Comment: `WHERE news_id = :news_id` this isn't `mysqli()` ;-)

Comment: To further elaborate on what @Fred-ii- said, please see this [reference material](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
$readGallery = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE news_id = ?");
```

to

```
$readGallery = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE news_id = :news_id");
```

Comment: Weren't you supposed to be having lunch? lol +1 for ya, why not ;-)

Comment: well I belong to a timezone where its almost Tuesday 8th march 2014 :-)

Comment: Breakfast then, or late night snack ;-) It's lunchtime here.